# How do I re-bind my validation events after an ajax form update?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to know how to re-bind validation on my form elements that have been injected in to the page via ajax.

This is the partial view that is rendered to the browser.

```
<tr>
    <td><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)%><%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)%></td>
    <td><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)%><%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName)%></td>
    <td><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IsAttending)%><%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsAttending)%></td>
    <td><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Food)%><%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.Food)%></td>
</tr>
```

I have also looked at MicrosoftMvcValidation.debug.js to see if there's any functions I can call and I've found this;

```
// register validation
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
  Sys.Application.remove_load(arguments.callee);
  Sys.Mvc.FormContext._Application_Load();
});
```

I've tried calling this code after the ajax call has completed and after the markup is injected in to the DOM, but no cigar.

I have stumbled across this question but It only talks about re-binding validation to an entire form that's been injected via ajax and that didn't help me either.
[mvc2-client-validation-isnt-working-when-getting-form-from-ajax-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892031/mvc2-client-validation-isnt-working-when-getting-form-from-ajax-call)

I should probably also mention that my partial view is generating duplicate ID's in the DOM. Some pointers on how to get around this would also be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASP.NET MVC Client Side Validation with Dynamic Contents](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/11/asp-net-mvc-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents.aspx)

This was a great starting point. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link Simon although as I mentioned already, I didn't want to load an entire form, I only want to load a fragment of a form, more specifically, I want to add a new line to my grid.